# cross-platform scripting for windows, Linux, MacOS X

Tags: windows, linux, scripting, multiplatform

I'm looking for cross-platform scripting (language) for windows, Linux, MacOS X.
I'm tired of .bat / bash .
I would like to do things like for example ,,lock workstation'' at automatic login (I had this in X-Window but the solution was pretty ugly; now, I would like that on MS Windows and not that ugly :-) ). 
Generally: automate tasks.
Or would I be better off with Windows Scripting Host?
PowerShell also comes to mind, but that's seems to Windows-only for my taste.
Can languages like Python, Ruby, (Java?) interact (elegantly? sensibly?) with WSH?
Also things like DBUS, DCOM, etc come to mind as part of the picture.
Currently I use a mixture of Java, .bat, bash, Ruby, Scala; some VBA for Excel. Which sometimes gets pretty ugly.
I would like a cross-platform general solution with/using ,,native'' parts close to OS-specifics. Like e.g. Ruby driving some Windows-specific stuff (just a guess).

What do You use?
TIA

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you're juggling on the edge of contradictory: you would like platform-independent (commendable) but also "close to OS specifics".

If, however, you put a bit more emphasis on platform independence, I've been entertaining the idea of using groovy (a more java-friendly relative of ruby) for general purpose scripting. When you need it, you get OS-specific behaviour by invoking OS shell commands.

My motivation is a bit different: I find groovy code to be more robust than that of bash, although I too will need a good multi-platform scripting tool for a project I'm developing.

Comment: Thanks. About the alleged ,,contradictory-ness'' : Generally cross-platform but able to integrate (call into) os-specifics, well. This not that rare.

Comment: I got the feeling you're leaning to something better than ruby + shell commands combination you mentioned: that's what I meant. I just said that it's not likely you'll find something better than that.

Comment: Groovy is good, but the slow startup of the jvm makes java a non-starter for short scripts IMO.

Comment: Agreed. If it's intended to be invoked multiple times from something else, it's next to useless. It's just a matter of the use cases one is interested in.

Answer (score 30):

I'm a huge fan of [Lua](http://www.lua.org/):

- Syntax is vaguely Pascal-like and works well in scripts.
- Superb power-to-weight ratio.  Superb engineering.  Very good design.
- Extremely portable to any platform with an ANSI C compiler.
- GUI support through wxLua and other bindings
- Some support for hiding OS differences in common tasks, e.g., the Lua File System add-on
- The core system and libraries are simple enough that you can understand **all** of what you're using, but still have excellent leverage compared to bash/bat.  Expressive power is comparable to Python or Ruby.
- You're not overwhelmed with libraries and frameworks, which can be a plus or a minus.
- There is an *excellent* book: Roberto Ierusalimschy's  [*Programming in Lua*](http://www.inf.puc-rio.br/~roberto/pil2/); you can get the [previous edition free online](http://www.lua.org/pil/).
- Performance beats tcl, perl, python, ruby
- For even faster performance on x86 hardware, there is LuaJIT.
- Finally, and this is the ace in the hole: if you run into any kind of platform-specific problem, it is *easy* to write platform-specific C code and load it into a Lua script dynamically.  Lua was designed with this task in mind and does it extremely well.  You can also easily dip into C for performance (e.g., compute MD5 checksum).

Over the last 3 to 5 years, I have been gradually migrating scripts from bash/ksh/awk/sed/grep/perl into Lua.  I have been *very* happy with the results.

Answer (score 17):

You could try [Batsh](https://github.com/BYVoid/Batsh)

> Batsh is a simple programming language that compiles to Bash and Windows Batch. It enables you to write your script once runs on all platforms without any additional dependency.

Answer (score 10):

Perl and Python are both available on almost every platform

Answer (score 5):

You could write your scripts in [Tcl](http://www.activestate.com/activetcl/).

- the syntax is simple and closer to
  what you'd expect from a script;
- it is cross-platform, and will run on all major platforms;
- you can easily create simple GUIs for your scripts in Tk, which will also work everywhere and use native controls;
- for the Windows-specific functions,
  you can use [Twapi](http://twapi.magicsplat.com/) (Win32 API
  bindings).
- you can install a Tclkit, which is a single file that is the whole Tcl distribution. There's no lengthy install process or hidden files or mysterious directories;

  - you can easily put a linux, windows and mac runtime on a single flash drive so you always have an interpreter handy even if there's not one installed locally.

Comment: Tcl also wins because you can install a Tclkit, which is a single file that is the whole Tcl distribution. There's no lengthy install process or hidden files or mysterious directories. Plus, you can easily put a linux, windows and mac runtime on a single flash drive so you always have an interpreter handy even if there's not one installed locally. And, of course, for GUI programming you get native widgets.

Answer (score 2):

> Like e.g. Ruby driving some Windows-specific stuff

[It certainly can](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1202262/ruby-win32-api-interface) and on the [Ruby on Windows](http://rubyonwindows.blogspot.com/) blog you can find lots of examples also there's a chapter in the Pickaxe book and in the [humble](http://www.humblelittlerubybook.com/book/html/chapter4.html) one.

Answer (score 0):

there is possibility for UNIX and UNIX like platforms in shell, but I don`t think that this what you are asking for is possible in any scripting language because of windows.

For UNIX systems you can use this:

```
#!/bin/sh

TYPE=`uname`;
echo 'this is ' ${TYPE};

if [ ${TYPE} = HP-UX ]
   then bdf /var;
elif [ ${TYPE} = Linux ]
   then df -h /var;
elif [ ${TYPE} = FreeBSD ]
   then df -k /var;
else echo "Unsupported OS - ${TYPE}"
fi
```

I hope it will help you!

[source](http://unixhacking.com/multiplatform-shell-script/)

Answer (score -1):

I would use C# with Mono.

Comment: That strikes me as an odd choice for scripting. In bash, e.g., you show the contents of a file with `cat file.txt`; in groovy with `println new File("file.txt").text`: how much code (+ compilation) would you have to do with C#? C# may be a nice general purpose OO language, but one thing it does not do well is support scripting.

Comment: Just for reference (without implying that c# is good for scripting) in C# you would write: File.ReadAllText("file.txt") in a repl environment (which is included in mono: http://www.mono-project.com/CsharpRepl )

Answer (score -1):

Not sure if you still need it, but if so, try ant ( http://ant.apache.org/ ). It's a cross platform "script language". Basically, a ant file is a xml file interpreted by a JVM programm.

Comment: I don't recommend this. I had the pleasure to work with Ant before and even when it works, it's such a round trip and odd type of programming, due to its declarative nature. It's no similar substitution to bash or batch programming.