# mvn exec:exec with '<' in commandlineArgs

Tags: maven, ssh, putty, plink

I need to run a command that contains '<' in it.

I can run it from the command line, but it throws error when I put it into mvn exec.

The command:

```
c:\apps\putty\plink.exe myuser@myhost -T -ssh -2 $SHELL /dev/stdin 'a b c d' < test.sh
```

test.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "execution parameters: $@"
```

Command line output:

> execution parameters: a b c d

pom.xml:

```
<plugin> 
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId> 
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId> 
                <version>1.4.0</version> 
                <executions> 
                    <execution>
                        <id>test</id>
                        <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>exec</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration><executable>c:\apps\putty\plink.exe</executable>
                            <commandlineArgs>"myuser@myhost -T -ssh -2 $SHELL /dev/stdin 'a b c d' < test.sh"</commandlineArgs>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
            </executions> 
        </plugin>
```

**I tried to change '<' to '&lt;', putting commandlineArgs into CDATA, put doubleqoutes (") everywhere but could not get this to work.**

```
[DEBUG] Executing command line: [c:\apps\putty\plink.exe, > myuser@myhost -T -ssh -2 -pw tomcat  $SHELL /dev/stdin 'a b c d' &lt; test.sh] 
Unable to open connection: Host does not exist[INFO]
------------------------------------------------------------------------ 
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
```

or:

```
[DEBUG] Executing command line: [c:\apps\putty\plink.exe, myuser@myhost, -T, -ssh, -2, -pw, tomcat, $SHELL /dev /stdin 'a b c d' &lt; test.sh] 
bash: test.sh: No such file or directory [INFO]
------------------------------------------------------------------------ 
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
```

I'm suspecting the '<' parameter, but I'm not sure what is the real problem.

Any tips?

UPDATE: when I say "**I tried to change '<' to '&lt;', putting commandlineArgs into CDATA, put doubleqoutes (") everywhere but could not get this to work.**" - I mean it!

Comment: Tried: <commandlineArgs><![CDATA[myuser@myhost -T -ssh -2 "$SHELL /dev/stdin 'a b c d' < test.sh"]]></commandlineArgs>

Comment: Also tried: <commandlineArgs><myuser@myhost -T -ssh -2 "$SHELL /dev/stdin 'a b c d' &lt; test.sh"</commandlineArgs>

Comment: Also tried: <commandlineArgs><![CDATA["myuser@myhost -T -ssh -2 $SHELL /dev/stdin 'a b c d' < test.sh"]]></commandlineArgs>

Comment: Just  to be on the same page as you: you are trying to execute a command on a remote machine, then use the result of that as command like args for Maven? From this: `<commandlineArgs>"myuser@myhost -T -ssh -2 $SHELL /dev/stdin 'a b c d' < test.sh"</commandlineArgs>` Maven somehow concludes that `myhost -T -ssh -2 $SHELL /dev/stdin 'a b c d' < test.sh` is the host.

Comment: The issue is not with plink nor with bash since the command line above is working. The question is how should I pass it to mvn exec:exec to make it run the same :-)

Answer (score 1):

It's working if I wrap it inside a .bat file:

```
@echo off
set plinkExec=%1
set env=%2
set user=%3
set pass=%4
set shellPath=%5
...

%plinkExec% %user%@%env% -T -ssh -2 -pw %pass% $SHELL /dev/stdin '...' < %shellPath%
```

Not nice, but does the magic :-)

Answer (score 1):

There is a difference between a system command and a shell command. Pipes and stream redirections are shell syntax.

A system command typically only launches a program with given parameters, such as

- `notepad.exe myfile.txt`
- `java -jar my-program.jar`

System commands can be passed to a simple call of an some `exec` function of various APIs (Java's `java.lang.Runtime.getRuntime().exec()`, PHP's backticks, etc).

Shell commands then are specific syntax of the shell processing it and Maven has no idea what shell you use.

Typically, shells provide a way to execute their command as a parameter to their executable. So if you want to use a shell command, you need to pass it e.g. like this:

```
            <configuration>
                <executable>bash</executable>
                <arguments>
                    <argument>-c</argument>
                    <argument>java -jar myprogram.jar < input.txt > output.txt</argument>
                </arguments>
            </configuration>
```

For Windows that would be

```
            <configuration>
                <executable>path/to/cmd.exe</executable>
                <arguments>
                    <argument>/C</argument>
                    <argument>java -jar myprogram.jar < input.txt > output.txt</argument>
                </arguments>
            </configuration>
```

You could use some [cross-platform shell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2637214/cross-platform-scripting-for-windows-linux-macos-x), e.g. Groovy.

Hope that helps.

Comment: You missed the plugin's artifact section. Is that a working example using `exec-maven-plugin`?
About groovy tip: I've already found that out: if you need to do something complex with maven then: a) you are using the wrong tool b) you can do it with groovy-maven-plugin ;-)

Comment: Yes, that's for the standard exec plugin. I haven't tried this exact code but I recall I used this for both linux and windows. Effectively it turns into:

    `bash "-c" "java ..."`

Answer (score 0):

You specifically asked for `mvn exec:exec`. But assuming you rather need to run a command with redirection, another way is to use a plugin that can handle streams itself, e.g. Maven Ant Plugin. Notice the `input="..."`:

```
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.8</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>verify</phase>
                    <goals> <goal>run</goal> </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <target name="run">
                            <exec dir="${work.dir}" executable="java" input="input.txt">
                                <arg value="-jar"/>
                                <arg file="${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}.jar"/>
                            </exec>
                        </target>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Comment: Ok :) Updated - added the phase which is necessary, and an example of how to point to the jar produced by the build. Greetings to Budapest from Brno.