# Automating front-end tasks

Tags: javascript, node.js, automation, gulp, frontend

I want to run a script that asking for the name, and then it creates directory with the same name where the current work directory is and three files inside with name.html, name.js, name.scss. then make some initial some markup inside HTML file, some initial javascript inside js file and some default or init style inside scss file.
something like React scaffolding I believe. but in whatever project in frontend universe and not only React js

which technology/language should I use to get it cross-platform?  node, npm, gulp, python, javascript, bash

thanks in advance

Comment: This question is opinion based, which is off-topic for SO. You've listed some server-side technologies that would not make a difference as far as cross-platform is concerned. Even .NET is cross-platform now that it's "open-source."

Answer (score 0):

This may be a duplicate - take a look at this post and see if it helps

[cross-platform scripting for windows, Linux, MacOS X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2637214/cross-platform-scripting-for-windows-linux-macos-x)

Comment: I want to use things already available in the projects like npm, node, gulp python or bash. and I asked to find out if there is some dedicated to the frontend