# Resizing windows using Ruby?

Tags: windows, ruby

I am trying to resize the window of another open application via ruby but I am not sure how to go about doing this.

I am guessing this may be possible using the Ruby Win32API, but to be honest I don't really know where to start looking.

If one of you guys could point me in the right direction it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1202262/ruby-win32-api-interface

Answer (score 2):

You're probably going to need some combination of [APIs for locating/identifying your target window](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff468919%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) and for [getting the resize message to them](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms632590%28v=VS.85%29.aspx).

- There may be something in [this thread](http://groups.google.com/group/comp.lang.ruby/browse_thread/thread/69e3b869663ffa72), and
- [This entry](http://ruby-doc.org/docs/ProgrammingRuby/html/lib_windows.html) from the Pickaxe book looks like a promising example (scroll down to the Win32API part), and
- one of the answers to [this SuperUser question](https://superuser.com/questions/31733/does-anyone-know-of-a-simple-command-line-is-good-app-to-close-windows-by-their) also looks like it might be useful

Comment: By the way I have found out what to do and have got my code working, so thanks again for the pointers