# Copying files in use with Ruby

Tags: ruby, volume-shadow-service

I need to copy some files that are in use by windows with a ruby script. The OS will either be Windows XP or Windows 7 both 32-bit. Can anyone point me to some information on using Volume Shadow copy with ruby? Is there a gem for this? I would prefer a solution that does not require administrator privileges but whatever works.

I would also be interested in checking if a file is in use before coping / deleting. Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1):

If there isn't a Ruby library for that purpose you could just use the [Windows Volume Shadow Copy API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384648(v=vs.85).aspx) directly via [Ruby's WIN32 API](http://www.ruby-doc.org/docs/ProgrammingRuby/html/win32.html) (or [WIN32 OLE](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/win32ole/rdoc/index.html), if available).  [Here's a useful thread on using Win32API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1202262/ruby-win32-api-interface).