# Ruby method for convering Windows short path into long path?

Tags: ruby, windows, path

Is there a built-in method in Ruby to convert a Windows short path like

```
C:\PROGRA~2\MICROS~1.0\VC\bin\amd64
```

into its corresponding long path

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\bin\amd64
```

I've tried

- `File.expand_path(short_path)`
- `Pathname.new(short_path).cleanpath`
- `Pathname.new(short_path).realpath`
- `Dir.chdir(short_path) { Dir.pwd }`

but none of these worked.

If possible, I'd like to avoid calling the Win32 API directly like in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8142448/1127485), or ugly work-arounds like spawning PowerShell:

```
%x{powershell (Get-Item -LiteralPath #{short_path}).FullName}
```

Comment: Just a suggestion: would you mind to try to `Dir.chdir` followed by `Dir.pwd`.

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't work either. I'll update my question.

Answer (score 3):

Here is one possible workaround:

```
path=Dir.mktmpdir('vendor')
=> "C:/Users/ADMINI~1/AppData/Local/Temp/1/vendor20160727-12668-ywfjol"

Dir.glob(path)[0]
=> "C:/Users/Administrator/AppData/Local/Temp/1/vendor20160727-12668-ywfjol"
```

Comment: But how does that help to convert arbitrary paths?

Comment: Kernel API call might be the perfect solution to solve this. https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/blob/master/lib/vagrant/util/windows_path.rb#L15

Comment: That indeed looks like an interesting solution as Fiddle seems to be part of stdlib since Ruby 2.0.